# Understanding censorship in the game "Vivid Army"

Tags: grammar, words, culture

Recently I played a game which is call **Vivid Army** and there's a little conversation between me and this guy but I found that there's some word is censored.

**7873 is me.** As you can see I have written **"hehe n**..."** but this is not what I original wrote. What I wrote is **"hehe nice..."** So why the **"i-c-e"** is censored?

[image]

Here is another example of some word's that censored.

[image]

Is it those censored words mean swear word in Japanese?

Comment: This seems like a question for whatever platform this conversation took place on.

Comment: This is looking more and more like a coding problem than a language problem.

Comment: It could be a very strange kind of [Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), but I cannot fathom what would be the issues in those words.

Comment: I) I don't think any of the example can be offensive in Japanese. ii) [Unofficial wiki of the game](https://vivid-army.game-info.wiki/d/%BE%AE%A5%CD%A5%BF%A1%A6%BE%AE%B5%BB#content_2) lists some of the censored words (rather, combination of letters). Some of them are Japanese, others sensitive only in China, and some are just plain puzzling. I think the censoring system is poorly constructed.

Comment: Maybe 'ice' is censored because of the US organization ICE? It's a long shot though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason these words (or combination of letters) should be censored in Japanese language. To my full imagination, there are no slang, rhyme, abbreviation or metaphor that makes these phrases offensive.

In [an unofficial wiki of the game](https://vivid-army.game-info.wiki/d/%BE%AE%A5%CD%A5%BF%A1%A6%BE%AE%B5%BB#content_2), they list some of the words/phrases that are sensored in the in-game chat. The writer seems to agree with us; the description starts with "There are oddly many 伏字 (censoring with **), which sometimes makes the chat incomprehensible".

Anyway, to read the article---

- Some of the words are understandable as vulgar or violent; 殺す (to kill), ﾀﾋ (as in 死) etc.
- Many words that can (ever) have political meanings are also censored; nations' names, 自由 freedom, etc.
- Others includes those which are fine in Japanese, but seem to be censored in terms of Chinese language or government; "89", the kanji "操" (accordning to the wiki, it's a part of insulting phrase in Chinese).
- However, many others are still very puzzling; "ri" (only in lower case), "コン", "ssa", "合成"  to name a few.

Apparently the censorship is conducted in a least sophisticated way (see [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) as suggested by [@conman](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/16022/conman)). It is also apparent that the administrators are very sensitive to any word they  come up with. However, these words or parts in your examples have no problem in Japanese: they are false-positives.

Answer (score 2):

The programming group that wrote the censoring algorithm probably don't have native English speakers on board, either that or their voices are simply blatantly ignored.

have => h__v : "av" is abbreviation for adult video

nice => n___ : "ice" is another name for crystal meth.

future => __t__e : "fu" = f__k you, not so sure about "ur" though.

From observation, their algorithm seems to be: (1) Remove all spaces in the text. (2) Search and replace all letter combination from a dubious "list of offensive words".

(I don't think the Japanese are to be blamed for this. Given their craftsmen ethics and mentality, in Japan, something as crude as this wouldn't be able to set a single step past the quality (or even functional) review office.